# Not able to run dalekjs test scripts behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, dalekjs

I am trying to run Dalekjs test scripts behind proxy but I get the following error message

D:\dalek>dalek .\test\mytest.js
Running tests
Running Browser: PhantomJS
OS: windows 7 32bit
Browser Version: 1.9.7

RUNNING TEST - "Page title is correct"

> OPEN http://www.google.co.in
>   x TITLE
>   0 EXPECTED: Google
>   0 FOUND: Proxy Authorization Required
>   0 MESSAGE: It has title
>   x TEST - "Page title is correct" FAILED

0/1 assertions passed. Elapsed Time: 1.09 sec

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you need to use the corporate web proxy which requires authentication. Have you tried to set up dalek.js to use your default browser (which I guess has the correct proxy settings) using the `--browser <browsername>` command line switch?

See http://dalekjs.com/pages/getStarted.html#realbrowser on how to add browser support to dalek.js.